# Smartgrid, flexbox, расстановка элементов

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Нужно сделать вот такой блок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что получается у меня:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Препроцессор Less, но думаю здесь это не важно)
Код:

```css
.back {
 background: #222222;

.items {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 
 .item {
  .col();
  .size(6);
   .works__date {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 109px;
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
   }
   .works__title {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 43px;
    font-weight: 600;
   }
   .works__desc {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
   }
   
   
 }
}
}
```

```html
<section class="back">
        <div class="items">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="item">
                    <span class="works__date">
                        Jan 4, 2016   |   In Culture
                    </span>
                    <h3 class="works__title">
                       Akita Inu Dog 
                    </h3>
                    <p class="works__desc">
                        Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed odio dui. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>

                        <p class="works__desc">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed posuere consectetur</p> 
                    
                </div>
                

            </div>
            <div class="item">
                    <img class="works__img" src="img/right_work.png" alt="">
                </div>
            
                </div>

        
    </section>
```

В Коде только два блока первой строки. Разместить хочу их в одной строке.
Фон первого вне контейнера. Картинка тоже вне контейнера. Уже голову сломал, что делаю не так...

Comment: https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/bLXVbe?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  font-size: 50px;
}
.item-text {
  background-color: red;
}
.item-img {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item-text">Много текста</div>
  <div class="item item-img">Картинка</div>
  <div class="item item-img">Картинка</div>
  <div class="item item-text">Много текста</div>
  
</div>
```

И если вы используете библиотеку смартгрид Лаврика,то я надеюсь, не забыли подключить её к своему less-файлу)))

Comment: Все подключено. Это уже третий блок этого шаблона. Не могу понять где туплю)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qs76nu0n/

Comment: @ДенисДоня https://jsfiddle.net/qs76nu0n/26/

Comment: @ДенисДоня во-первых,поменяйте теги контейнер и итем местами. И вы ресет стилей сделали? в смартгриде вроде это миксин .reset()

Comment: простите,кривая ссылка на фидл была https://jsfiddle.net/qs76nu0n/28/

Comment: Все вышло, спасибо. Правда Блок с текстом вне контейнера получился...странно https://ibb.co/hEYQF7

Comment: @ДенисДоня покажите код,мб увижу в чем дело

Comment: Вот так выглядит код в данный момент. https://jsfiddle.net/dk7gg5d4/

Comment: @ДенисДоня чтобы сделать отступы,задавайте их родителю, а не элементам внутри https://jsfiddle.net/qs76nu0n/37/